# How to make jasper report make 2nd page if data wont fit in 1st page

Tags: java

I want to know if its possible to make jasper report automatically make 2nd page if data from database wont fit in 1st page . Please give a snippet of code .

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement any specific code for that case. Jasper reports will expand your data to a second page automatically.

The example of jrxml file  http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v60/jrxml-sources-and-jasper-files

Comment: I use the table component in ireport it only shows 4 data , infact i have more than 20+ data in my database